# Select all datetime objects between two points from the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bazillion files with dates embedded in the filenames. I parsed the files into dict where the key is the datetime extracted from the name, and the value is the path.

I want to select all files from the set where the datetime is between time A and time B.

My first thought is to transform the dict into a list of tuples and then sort.

```
file_list = [(k, v) for k, v in file_dict.items()]
file_list = sorted(file_list, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Then I'll select from the list between the two points using a for loop.

```
first = -1
last = -1
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    if first < 0 and file_list[i] > time_a:
        first = i
    if last < 0 and file_list[i] > time_b:
        last = i
if first > -1 and last > -1:
    new_dict = {k: v for k, v in file_list[first:last]}
else:
    whatever()
```

Strictly speaking, this is good enough, but it doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a better way to select these dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing one line list comprehension, you can filter the output in the expression, as in the code below. If there are no dates between A and B, then you will get an empty dictionary, since none of the items will match the if condition.

```
 {k:v for k, v in file_list if k >= time_a and k <= time_b}
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.